# Automate YouTube short page using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I tried to automate YouTube short video page with Selenium but I ended with error "no such element" each time I tried to find the comment button by CSS selector or by Xpath.

I want to click the comment button in the YouTube page.

Comment: If you want assistance, please follow this guide, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Just a quick note: your questions here are generally very short, and are often closed or downvoted. You will shortly be subject to an automatic question ban because your questions are not well received. Is there a place on the web where you could ask questions in your native language?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set the path to the webdriver executable.
webdriver_path = 'path/to/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriver_path)

video_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/your-short-video-url'
driver.get(video_url)

# Wait until the comment button is visible.
comment_button_locator = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-button-renderer#comment-button')
comment_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(comment_button_locator))
comment_button.click()

# Now you can interact with the comment section or perform any other actions you need.

# Close the browser window.
driver.quit()
```

Comment: I already tried that but it didn't worked, Did you tried that code on your local machine